# How to render a Modal within a Tab Screen in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I need to render a modal when the user press in the middle button. I'm using `react-native-raw-bottom-sheet` library to provide a Modal to my application.
I tried to pass a prop `isFocused={props.navigation.isFocused}`  inside the <Tab.Screen> but the problem is when I pass the props to  based if is or not focused in the  the  is rendered two times instead one.

I also tried to trigger the modal direct by the  but without success.

My problematic is, when the user press the  i need render the new  that will contain the hole logic of the content in the modal and also will render the modal.

[image: Bottom Tab Navigation]

**My tab.routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import TabButton from '../components/Tab/Button';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import Home from '../containers/Home';
import Adjustment from '../containers/Adjustment';
import Graphic from '../containers/Graphic';
import Help from '../containers/Help';
import NewTransaction from '../containers/NewTransaction';

const icons = {
  Home: {
    name: 'home',
  },
  Graphic: {
    name: 'pie-chart',
  },
  NewTransaction: {
    name: 'notifications-none',
  },
  Help: {
    name: 'help-outline',
  },
  Adjustment: {
    name: 'settings',
  },
};

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabRoutes = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="HomeScreen"
    screenOptions={({route, navigation}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => {
        if (route.name === 'NewTransaction') {
          return <TabButton focused={focused} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewTransaction')} />;
        }
        const {name} = icons[route.name];
        return <Icon name={name} size={size} color={color} />;
      },
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
      keyboardHidesTabBar: true,
      activeTintColor: '#f8b006',
      inactiveTintColor: '#1C3041',
      style: {
        height: 60,
      },
      iconStyle: {
        marginTop: 5,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        marginBottom: 10,
      },
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen
      options={{
        title: 'Home',
      }}
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      options={{
        title: 'Gráfico',
      }}
      name="Graphic"
      component={Graphic}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      options={{
        title: '',
      }}
      name="NewTransaction"
      component={NewTransaction}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      options={{
        title: 'Ajuda',
      }}
      name="Help"
      component={Help}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      options={{
        title: 'Ajustes',
      }}
      name="Adjustment">
      {(props) => (
        <Adjustment isVisible={props.navigation.isFocused()} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')} />
      )}
    </Tab.Screen>
  </Tab.Navigator>
);

export default TabRoutes;
```

**Tab/Button/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import Button from './styles';

const TabButton = ({onPress, focused}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
      <Button focused={focused}>
        <Icon name="add" size={35} color={'white'} />
      </Button>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};

export default TabButton;
```

**And the component that will display the modal content**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
const NewTransaction = ({isVisible}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Welcome to NewTransactions </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default NewTransaction;
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my home tab it looks like to you

[image]

I custom tab bar with code but the add button is not a screen it is just a button and popup options to select

[image]

```
import {hideModalCreate, showModalCreate} from '@features/loading/actions';
import CreateYCTV from '@features/main/CreateYCTV';
import HomeScreen from '@features/main/Home';
import Manager from '@features/main/Manager';
import Notification from '@features/main/Notification';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import images from '@res/icons';
import * as React from 'react';
import {Image, Pressable, View} from 'react-native';
import {Text, useTheme} from 'react-native-paper';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import ProductStack from './ProductStack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabBar({
  state,
  descriptors,
  navigation,
  showModalCreate,
  hideModalCreate,
  isShowModalCreate,
}) {
  const {colors} = useTheme();
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  const focusedOptions = descriptors[state.routes[state.index].key].options;

  if (focusedOptions.tabBarVisible === false) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        paddingBottom: Math.max(insets.bottom, 0),
      }}>
      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
        const label =
          options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
            ? options.tabBarLabel
            : options.title !== undefined
            ? options.title
            : route.name;

        const isFocused = state.index === index;

        const getSourceImage = (isFocused) => {
          switch (route.name) {
            case 'home':
              return isFocused ? images.tab_home1 : images.tab_home;
            case 'loans':
              return isFocused ? images.tab_searching1 : images.tab_searching;
            case 'notification':
              return isFocused ? images.notifications1 : images.notifications;
            case 'manager':
              return isFocused
                ? images.tab_paper_folder1
                : images.tab_paper_folder;
            default:
              return images.tab_add;
          }
        };

        const onPress = () => {
          if (route.name === 'create') {
            if (isShowModalCreate) {
              hideModalCreate();
              return;
            }
            showModalCreate();
            return;
          }
          hideModalCreate();
          const event = navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabPress',
            target: route.key,
            canPreventDefault: true,
          });

          if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        const onLongPress = () => {
          navigation.emit({
            type: 'tabLongPress',
            target: route.key,
          });
        };

        return (
          <Pressable
            accessibilityRole="button"
            accessibilityStates={isFocused ? ['selected'] : []}
            accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
            testID={options.tabBarTestID}
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              paddingVertical: 8,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
            }}>
            <Image source={getSourceImage(isFocused)} />
            {route.name != 'create' ? (
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: isFocused ? colors.primary : colors.placeholder,
                  fontSize: 10,
                  marginTop: 4,
                }}>
                {label}
              </Text>
            ) : null}
          </Pressable>
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
}

const Tabbar = ({showModalCreate, hideModalCreate, isShowModalCreate}) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      tabBar={(props) => (
        <MyTabBar
          isShowModalCreate={isShowModalCreate}
          showModalCreate={showModalCreate}
          {...props}
          hideModalCreate={hideModalCreate}
        />
      )}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          title: 'Trang chủ',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="loans"
        component={ProductStack}
        options={{
          title: 'Sản phẩm',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="create" component={CreateYCTV} />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="notification"
        component={Notification}
        options={{
          title: 'Thông báo',
          tabBarBadge: '13',
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="manager"
        component={Manager}
        options={{
          title: 'Quản lý',
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    isShowModalCreate: state.loading.isShowModalCreate,
  };
};

const mapDispatch = {
  showModalCreate: showModalCreate,
  hideModalCreate: hideModalCreate,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(Tabbar);
```

Comment: can you share me a more code i am confusing with showmodalCreate and hideModalCreate

Comment: Both function just change state isShowModalCreate in redux

Comment: it's not good way for me, i think that have a state who get the last view and your modal is in root component

Comment: @Anhdevit how did u make the modal come above the tab. It looks just like any other tab screen. I am trying to achieve the same but mine comes over the whole tab.